# Kintone Add Record API call always returns 'required field' error

Tags: javascript, php, api, rest, postman

Please help me!

It takes two days for me. So I would like to ask for your help.

In my app on Kintone, I have only required field as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYbbI.png)

In postman

```
Header
Content-Type  application/json
X-Cybozu-API-Token  b7EMUSEfcDCbb0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Request body with json format
{
   "app":xxx,
   "record": {
       "名": {
           "value": "三宅"
       }
   }
}


I got error as below.
{
    "code": "CB_VA01",
    "id": "1RY4iPgdkvHACFShdidq",
    "message": "入力内容が正しくありません。",
    "errors": {
        "record.名.value": {
            "messages": [
                "必須です。"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it. Please help me!

#Kintone
#Add Record api call error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I built a test app and used the script you provided, but it worked fine.

And then I tried to mess with the settings and code to recreate the same error, but the only way I was able to recreate it was by making the value empty as follows:

```
{
"app":XXX,
    "record": {
        "名": {
            "value": ""
        }
    }
}
```

The error is basically saying the field is a required field, so I'm assuming the value isn't properly set.
Could you check your settings (such as headers) and see if you are doing it correctly?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I set headers Content-Type application/json and X-Cybozu-API-Token also. I thought first "is it permission problem?". But I remove required in that field and try again. Then it worked well. But value is empty in database.

Comment: Hello July,

If it's a permission problem, it should give you the error code, GAIA_NO01, which says you cannot use the specified API with that token.

Before you removed the Required setting from the field, it didn't let you save the record because no value was input in the required field. However, after you removed the setting, even though the field still has no value, the request still added the record because the field isn't required anymore.

Like I said in the previous reply, the problem here is the value isn't correctly input in the field.

Continues to the next comment....

Comment: Your screenshot for the postman seemed to have been removed, but I remember your Headers had 11 headers instead of 10. 

I don't know about the postman in-depth, but when I created a new request, there were already 8 headers as default, so adding the two "X-Cybozu..." and "Content..." lines would make the total number of headers be 10. So I thought you had an extra line to your header, which might be causing the problem. Could you check into that?

Comment: Hello Chris, thank you for your help. Before I send request, the total number of headers is 10. When I get postman response, header number is 11. I think Cybozu added cookie header into my header list. Why the value is incorrect, I really don't know and I can't solve it.  :(